# All matrix/vector norms induce the same topology?

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm)

> all norms on $K^{m \times n}$ are equivalent; they induce the same topology on $K^{m \times n}$. This is true because the vector space $K^{m \times n}$ has the finite dimension $m \times n$.

So all $l^p, p\geq 1$ norms on $K^m$for some $m\in \mathbb N$ induce the same topology, same as other vector norms?

But if the dimension of $K^{m \times n}$ is not finite, the norms on $K^{m \times n}$ may not induce the same topology. So $L^p, p \geq 1$ norms may not induce the same topology on a functional space?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: *if the dimension of $K^{m \times n}$ is not finite*... seems absurd.

Comment: @Did: I meant if $m$ or $n$ is $\infty$.

Comment: This is fine, it's a standard result. All norms are equivalent on finite dimensional vector spaces, in infinite dimensions this is not true. See Lax Linear Algebra and Lax Functional Analysis for proofs and comments.

Comment: What does "induce the same topology" and "equivalent" mean in the context of our discussion?

Comment: @user89 Exactly the same thing. You **define** two norms to be equivalent if they induce the same topology.